# How to write old queries in new Gremlin 3.x syntax in javascript/typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, gremlin, azure-cosmosdb-gremlinapi

I need to write old queries from Gremlin 2.6 to 3.4 syntax in JS/TS, because in 2.6 i've done everything with strings and then i execute that string but now i want to use 3.4 syntax where i can use chaining methods.

First i need to convert this query, but i don't know what to do with this nested queries `out().simplePath()` and `label().is('Recording')`.

```
g.V().repeat(out().simplePath()).until(label().is('Recording'))
```

I'm thinking something like this to do but i'm not sure that is correct.

```
g.V().repeat(g.V().out().simplePath()).until(g.V().label().is('Recording'));
```

Also there is no more between function in gremlin so how can i get same result for this old function and also to write that in js/ts? (This is just part of a query)

```
.has('name', between('${partialPropertyName}', '${partialPropertyName}a'))
```

Thank you guys in front.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of quick answers.

There is still a `between()` predicate in Gremlin. I don't know if the database you are using supports it or not.

For your repeat until you can just do

```
g.V().repeat(out().simplePath()).until(hasLabel('Recording'))
```

The TinkerPop docs have good examples of all these steps. I would recommend giving the docs a quick read. Also feel free to do a search on "Practical Gremlin" I have several examples in there.

Edited to add example JavaScript imports

```
const gremlin = require('gremlin');
const Graph = gremlin.structure.Graph;
const __ = gremlin.process.statics;
const { t: { id },order,cardinality } = gremlin.process;
```

Edited again to point out that there is an `index.js` file in the root directory of the `gremlin` package that `npm install gremlin` creates. You can also find this file in the TinkerPop GitHub repo.

Cheers
Kelvin

Comment: I can't just type .repeat(out().simplePath()) because JS doesn't see out() function.  When i hover gremlin import i get "Could not find a declaration file for module 'gremlin'". That's why i had to create my own typings for gremlin in Typescript.

Comment: P.S. Your book is really good will definitely check it. One downside is that i need JavaScript code but as i could see you did it in Java and Groovy.

Comment: From JavaScript just import the necessary objects and use __.out()

Comment: I added some sample imports to my answer above

Comment: When i import or like you write require('gremlin') i still can't see all methods and types. Is there anything i can do to get all methods and types for gremlin in JS?

Comment: It might be worth doing a git clone of the TinkerPop source tree. That way you will have a local copy of the file with all the definitions in it. When I get a spare moment I will update the answer with a link to the specific file.

Comment: As an aside if you just do a console.log(gremlin) you will see everything you are looking for. You may also want to look at this file. https://github.com/apache/tinkerpop/blob/master/gremlin-javascript/src/main/javascript/gremlin-javascript/lib/process/traversal.js

Comment: I edited the example again to show how you can import all of order and cardinality also. You would then reference using syntax such as `order.decr`

Comment: I had an issue open against myself to add sample code and a discussion of using Node.js to Practical Gremlin. I added a sample which may be helpful. https://github.com/krlawrence/graph/blob/master/sample-code/glv-client.js

Comment: When i console.log(__) i can't find between method and of course get error __.between is not a function...

Comment: In their documentation you also can't find between method, so i think they removed it. Any other solution that can help archive between method?

Comment: Between is a predicate not a step. It’s part of P. Import  P and use P.between()

Comment: Sir you are my savior! Can you tell me just one more thing. I can't connect to my cosmos db with gremlin i always get server timeout respond. I've tried in Javascript and C# but still got same error. So now i am working on localhost. Do you maybe know why this occurs. I used same connection methods as in documentation.

Comment: Unfortunately I am not familiar with how Cosmos DB works. Hopefully someone else can help you with that.